# HTTPS redirect from ANY HTTP url for my domain

Tags: tomcat, redirect, iis-7, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build server that I'm using for CI running through IIS. I would very much like for ANY url on my domain to be redirected to the HTTPS version of the url.

I've followed the tutorial linked here: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/

```
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <clear />           


    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Subdirectory HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(^admin/.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule> 

        </rules>           
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Also, this is the current version of my web.config after following this tutorial:

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, because the main urls for my domain seem to redirect to https, but many of the subdomains just 404 unless you EXPLICITLY specify HTTPS. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a JavaScript protocol redirect and binding a new handler to all HTTP-80 (non secure) listeners, in which the default error page and default document are a static file with the Javascript redirect. See below for examples, including screenshots (linked). Default Document for INSECURE should also be `index.htm`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<!-- This is index.htm -->
<head><script>
if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
    window.location.protocol = "https:";
    window.location.reload();
}</head></html>
```

ASP Redirect solution:
`<% Response.Redirect "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL") %>`

PHP Redirect solution:
`<?php header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found'); header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]); ?>`

Handler config in IIS sites: [Handler config](http://snftech.tk/upload/Screenshot_45.png)

Error Pages in the INSECURE site:
[Custom error pages](http://snftech.tk/upload/Screenshot_47.png)

Comment: And I'll work on an ASP version of this in the meantime, and PHP if you want

Comment: It is done, added ASP and PHP solutions to the answer. They don't check anything, don't ask any questions, just redirect, short and sweet. If you use one of those, change the file type accordingly.